# Issue in making cross-domain call to Project server oData feed from SharePoint Add-In (app)

Tags: cross-domain, sharepoint-2013, project-server

I am developing a SharePoint Hosted Add-In which will display project server projects. I am using SP.RequestExecutor to make cross domain calls. It gives me the following error “Cannot find resource for the request ProjectData.”

I have given the Reporting (Project Server) Read permission in AppManifest file. Following is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', initializePage);
});

function initializePage() {
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", getProjectList);
}


function getProjectList() {

    var executor;
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

    executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/ProjectData/Projects?$filter=ProjectState eq 'In Progress'&$select=ProjectId,ProjectName&@target='" +
             hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
            alert(jsonObject.d.results);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.body);
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use `SP.AppContextSite(@target)`.

Try below URL  -

> url: appweburl + "/_api/ProjectData/Projects?$filter=ProjectState eq
>   'In Progress'&$select=ProjectId,ProjectName"

The permissions for your app should include Read permissions for Reporting.